# Two sites on the same server with unwanted redirection

Tags: .htaccess, https, redirect, apache2, certificate

I have two different sites
domain1.com
domain2.com

**Problem** : I only can access domain2.com by using www.domain2.com 
If i try domain2.com it redirects to domain1.com.

Configuration files: 
**domain1.com.conf**

> ```
>   <VirtualHost *:80>     
>      ServerName domain1.com
>      ServerAlias www.domain1.com
>      DocumentRoot /var/www/html
>    </VirtualHost>
>    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
>      <VirtualHost *:443>
>        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
>        ServerName www.domain1.com
>        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
>        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem
>        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/privkey.pem
>      </VirtualHost>
>    </IfModule>
> ```

**domain2.com.conf**

> ```
>    <VirtualHost *:80>
>            ServerName domain2.com
>            ServerAlias www.domain2.com
>            DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html/domain2.com/wordpress
>    </VirtualHost>
>    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
>    <VirtualHost *:443>
>            ServerAdmin gneri94@gmail.com
>            DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html/domain2.com/wordpress
>            ServerName www.domain2.com
>            Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
>            SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.com/fullchain.pem
>            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.com/privkey.pem
>    </VirtualHost>
>    </IfModule>
> ```

.htaccess in both sites

```
# BEGIN WordPress                         
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteBase / 
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

command `certbot certificates` returns:

> Certificate Name: domain1.com 
>   Domains: domain1.com www.domain1.com
>   Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem
>   Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/privkey.pem
>
> Certificate Name: domain2.com 
>   Domains: domain2.com www.domain2.com
>   Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.com/fullchain.pem
>   Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.com/privkey.pem

Comment: Have you tried from an alternative browser? It could be cache related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For port 80 vHost you have:

```
ServerName domain2.com
ServerAlias www.domain2.com
```

But for port 443 you only have:

```
ServerName www.domain2.com
```

(This applies to both domain1 and domain2.)

So if you access `https://domain2.com` it will get caught by the default vHost (ie. the first one that is defined: `www.domain1.com`)

You should also consider redirecting to the HTTPS (canonical) domain in the port 80 vHost.